# Matrix Power BI totals are not calculated

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

the sub-totals and grand-totals of the CA facturé, of the provision sur CA return 0 for the Dimfi project code which contains several lines.
On the other hand, for the Dimfi project code which contains a single line, the subtotal is displayed correctly.

Here is a formula I used

```
CA Facturé = 
      IF(
        OR(
            CONTAINSSTRING(SELECTEDVALUE('ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document]),"AV")
           ,CONTAINSSTRING(SELECTEDVALUE('ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document]),"VT")
        )
        ,[Solde]
        ,0
      )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UZTc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D88Nt.png)

when i replaced SELECTEDVALUE() by MAX() it gaves this result, the total of CA FACTURE is incorrect

[image]

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to SO. Please, add the picture and the code text (text not a picture) directly to the question body

Comment: This is because you use `SELECTEDVALUE()` it returns `BLANK()` when it's a not single value. then the  `OR(BLANK(),BLANK())` returns `FALSE()` this is how you get 0

Comment: I added the code text, please how can i resolve it?

Comment: I can't use containstring function without selectedvalue(), it give me error

Comment: Great, I'll look through tomorrow.

Comment: Hey, when i replaced SELECTEDVALUE() by MAX(), it gives me the SOLDE instead of summing the lines. so, the total of CA FACTURE is incorrect

Comment: yep, I' ll look through soon

Comment: ok, I'll be grateful. I added a picture of result, see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas before for measure commenting.

DAX calculates result separately for each row you have in the matrix.
On a screenshot you have 23 rows, so the measure calculates 23 times. Each row has it own context (some values that affect the result).

When DAX calculates row - 1, the context of calculation is `Dimfi code project = E002P00019-01`

So DAX filters your table before measure returns you a value like this:

```
CALCUATE(
    [CA Facturé] -- the body of the measure works after filtering
    ,'ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[Dimfi code project] = "E002P00019-01"
    -- the table consist of unique [Dimfi code project] value 
    -- and multiple dependent [N° de document] values that are hidden in the matrix.
)
```

When DAX calculates row - 6, the context of the calculation is `Dimfi code project = E002P00021-01` and `[N° de document]=AVPREE0020001795`

So DAX filters your table before measure returns you a value like this:

```
CALCUATE(
    [CA Facturé]
    ,'ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[Dimfi code project] = "E002P00021-01"
    ,'ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document]="AVPREE0020001795"
    -- the table consist of unique [Dimfi code project] value 
    -- and unique  [N° de document] value
    -- may be you get a table with 1 row
)
```

For Total you have all table for the measure. The table is not filtered.
Now comments:

```
CA Facturé =
```

I want to collect all visible in the context unique values for [N° de document] with `VALUES()` function.
It's about the same as `DISTINCT()`,
but `DISTINCT()` excludes blank values from the result.
`VALUES()` will return all unique values (codes) for total row in the matrix,
multiple `[N° de document]` for rolled up `[Dimfi code project]`,
1 value if you see `[N° de document]` in the matrix row:

```
VAR docNumValues = VALUES('ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document])
```

`docNumValues` is a table with 1 column and all unique [N° de document] that are visible in the context
for row 5 of the matrixit it looks like this:

| N° de document |
| --- |
| AVPREE0020001795 |
| REPOE0020001164 |
| VTPRE0020009986 |
| ... |
| VTPRE0020018283 |

ADDCOLUMNS in this measure creates a virtual table.
It consist of as that much row as you have unique [N° de document] values in a certain row of matrix.

ADDCOLUMNS is an iterative function it means that goes through each row
of base table `docNumValues` and evaluate an expression that is presented after new column name.

the first iteration of ADDCOLUMNS will add a filter to CALCULATE  like this:

```
CALCULATE(
    IF(...
    )
    ,`[N° de document]=AVPREE0020001795`
)
```

and CALCULATE will cut a table for calculation with a 1 unique value.

```
VAR withSum = 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            docNumValues
            ,"@Sum",CALCULATE( -- adds filter `[N° de document]=...
                       IF(
                          OR(
                              LEFT(
                                  SELECTEDVALUE('ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document])
                              ,2
                              )="AV"
                             ,LEFT(
                                  SELECTEDVALUE('ECRITURE COMPTABLE'[N° de document])
                              ,2
                              )="VT"
                          )
                         ,[Solde]
                         ,0
                       )
                    )
       )
```

AS a result of the ADDCOLUMNS() for row 5 of the matrix you will have a virtual table `withSum` like this:

| N° de document | @Sum |
| --- | --- |
| AVPREE0020001795 | -5823.10 |
| REPOE0020001164 | 0 |
| VTPRE0020009986 | 10 493.55 |
| ... | ... |
| VTPRE0020018283 | 5505.07 |

Than you just make a summation of all values that you have in the table.

```
RETURN
    SUMX(withSum,[@Sum])
```

I used `LEFT()` instead of `CONTAINSSTRING()`, because it's safety - it can be that you will have the code like RTVT, and `CONTAINSSTRING()` will return `TRUE()`

Comment: Can you explain me the code text, please?

Comment: Happy New Year ! Best wishes !

Comment: just added some explanation, please read. English is not my native, so you can ask if any question.